# Apache2 301 Redirect Not Working

Tags: apache

I have attempted to read various documentation, as well as other answers online, and I cannot find a solution to my problem.

**Here is my issue:**

I have a permanent www to non-www redirect setup to point traffic from www.domain.com to domain.com

This works, but I am having issues when trying to visit specific urls. For example:

We have three PDFS that we would like people to be able to download via:

***domain.com/paper/somepdfname.pdf***

When i visit the url like this it works, but if I try to visit something like this:

***www.domain.com/paper/somepdfname.pdf***

The browser gets redirected, and strips one of the slashes out, resulting in "the site cannot be reached error". This is the url I end up with in the browser:

***domain.compaper/somepdfname.pdf***

I think its pretty clear that I need to somehow make sure there is a forward slash put before the paper, but I do not know how to do this. Below you will find my .htaccess directive for handling the redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1/ [R=301,L]
```